# Why does it feel like a plane accelerates just before touching down?

Tags: landing, aircraft-physics

On commercial flights it often feels like the plane gets faster just before touching down. What creates that sensation?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just subjective?  It's been a while since I've flown commercial, but I don't remember any such feeling.  And I don't notice a "feeling" in light airplanes, other than the visual sensation from being closer to the ground.

Comment: @jamesqf I am not sure what a feeling could be, if not subjective.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The aircraft flares just before touching down. It descends with a constant velocity, and just before touching down pulls the nose up to reduce the descent. This results in a higher angle of attack, more lift, and a vertical deceleration of the airplane. A passenger perceives this vertical deceleration as a force. Direction of the force is straight down and the aircraft is nose up, you're leaning back, so there is a component of (gravity + vertical deceleration) that pushes you into the back of your seat.

This same effect is used in flight simulators with a motion base. Upon accelerating, the simulator pushes forward like the aircraft does, but also slowly rotates backwards so that the pilot feels sustained seat back pressure. He cannot see the leaning back angle inside the simulator because the horizon of the projected outside visual image does not move. As happens in the aircraft: look forward in the aircraft and your view of the inside of the aircraft is always the same, irrespective of aircraft angle.

[image]
So for your eyes there is no apparent tilt, the inner ear senses rearwards force, and there is increased pressure from the seat backrest. The brain translates this into perceived forward acceleration.

Comment: In other words: *you* are being accelerated *downwards* into your seat by gravity as well as the seat being accelerated *upwards* into you by the flare, but you *think* that your seat is being accelerated *forwards* into you.

Comment: Gravity - yes. Additional upward acceleration from flare - yes. But your seat is tilted backwards, that is why the back feels some of the vertical acceleration.

Comment: While highly upvoted, this answer may not be correct. When the flare occurs, the nose rotates up which should decrease the pressure on the passenger back due to inertia. This should create a feeling of being decelerated in the forward direction. An illustration would be helpful.

Comment: @mins During rotation the flare action would contribute a small amount of reduction in the apparent "backwards" force due to the rotating gravity vector, but the movement is slow enough that the effect is minimal.  The dominant force would be gravity.  6 degrees of flare produces about 1m/s^2 apparent acceleration force into the back of the seat - about the same as the acceleration you would feel in a normal car accelerating from a stop (driving conservatively).

Comment: It depends on the centre of rotation. If this is located above the passenger, the rotational acceleration actually helps the back pressure (this is the way it's done in the simulator, with centre of rotation at the pilot's head, and rotation taking place slowly so the inner ear does not detect it). It depends on whether you're seated forward or aft of the centre of rotation: if you're sitting a couple of meters in front of it, the rotational acceleration actually helps. But after the rotation is completed, the resulting angle creates the back pressure feeling.

Comment: @mins Rotational acceleration is pretty small anyway. I'm assuming you're referring to rotational acceleration, not velocity, since you mentioned inertia.

Comment: @mins Actually, centre of rotation might very well be above the passenger seat since we're adding to the aircraft velocity vector. Passengers fwd of CoG go up due to rotation, but down due to landing speed * sin (glide slope).  Passengers aft of CoG go down with ω * distance + landing speed * sin glide slope. But you're right, a picture is worth 1000 words, I'll source a picture of a seated person in a back leaning chair with the gravitation and acceleration vectors.

Comment: @Koyovis: I don't think a leaning chair will help, it's not about the existence of a gravity component backwards in a static situation (nobody will challenge that), it's about how all forces combine during the flare. As for the rotation under elevator deflection being [around a center above the passenger seats](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Longitudinal_aircraft_stability_05.svg/500px-Longitudinal_aircraft_stability_05.svg.png) in a A320... I'm lost :-)

Comment: @mins at 0:50 in this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPyXLmg87s0) video: see the aircraft flare without the cockpit going up. I would call the cockpit the centre of rotation.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Gravity is exerting a downward force on you, but you're not actually being _accelerated_ downward. On the contrary, the net force exerted on you is upwards, so you're acceleration is upwards (i.e. your rate of descent is decreasing in magnitude.)

Answer (score 14):

Aside from the sensory effects already mentioned, there are also occasions when the pilot does indeed add a bit of power shortly before touchdown.  See, for example, comments [#5](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=761641#p10994929), [#16](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=761641#p10995007), and [#17](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=761641#p10995009) from [Adding Power Just Before Touchdown](http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=761641).

Comment: Yes, the sound of the engines spooling up will further add to the sensory inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Visual perception of your perspective; as the aircraft gets closer to the ground your field of view constricts and you are closer to terrain and other structures, making them appear to move faster past the jet than at altitude.

Comment: This is not only a visual sensation, because I recall this same feeling apart from looking out the window. It feels as if you are being pushed back in your seat.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're feeling is the brief float due to the ground effect. Within about 10 feet of the ground the air being forced down by the wing encounters the resistance of the ground. It actually arrests the downward motion unless the angle is pretty steep and that float gives a slight sinking feeling that feels like acceleration. Sometime too the pilot will add a little throttle to transition out of the ground effect a little less abruptly.

Comment: Yes ground effect helps in arresting the downward velocity. But how does that transform into a sensation of forward acceleration?

Comment: You'd have to instrument it to see the small changes and there may be a small decrease in drag. What we feel in the air isn't what necessarily what is really happening which is why we fly by instruments and not feel in low visibility situations. Our senses fool us very readily.

Answer (score 0):

As the plane descends into ground effect, it may actually accelerate if the engines are producing enough thrust, since in ground effect the plane requires much less power to keep "flying".  Power from the engines will translate into speed, if not height.

I don't know if it happens often in real world landing configurations, but it's certainly possible.  To make it happen for sure, set the power so that the plane is just barely descending, and when it gets into ground effect, it will certainly speed up measurably.

Answer (score -1):

when the flaps are lowered more power is applied to make up for the losses sometimes I fell a drop in speed and then a little surge in acceleration.

Comment: Welcome! Do you suggest the flaps are lowered just before touchdown?

Answer (score -6):

It does accelerate just before touching down in case something goes wrong with the landing gear and the plane has to immediately take off again.

Comment: DV - I'm sorry for any confusion, but this is not what I am referring to. I am asking about a phenomena felt during a routine and successful landing.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Do you have any reference for this? It does happen during aircraft carrier landings, but that's a very special case and not really what this question is about.